# Best practice for schema naming of entity/collection

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I am building a Graphql Schema and I was wandering what is the best practice of returning single vs collection items of a type. Let's say we want to retrieve `users`,

One option (if possible somehow) would be to have a query like this where the `ID` is optional, if `ID` is passed we return a single item, if not a collection of all users

```js
query {
  user (id: 1234) {
    name
  }
}

// return a single [User]
```

```js
query {
  user (id: null) {
    name
  }
}

// return a collection [User,User,User,...]
```

Another option would be to have `user` and `users`

```js
query {
  user (id: 1234) {
    name
  }
}

// return a single User
```

```js
query {
  users {
    name
  }
}

// return a collection [User,User,User,...]
```

I was wondering what is the best practice, or if you can pin-point me some resources related to that to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the singular and plurals nouns to name the query field that return a single object and a list of object respectively. I think this naming style is very natural to most of the developers.

So to return a single user, it is :

```
type Query {
   user(id:Int!) : User
}
```

It always return a single user. Just make the `id` input parameter as mandatory such that it cannot accept `NULL`.

And to return a list of user , normally it is:

```
type Query {
   users : [User]
}
```

But in case it can have many users , most probably you need to consider something like pagination that allows developers to get the user page by page. For the offset -based pagination , I am doing something like below :

```
type Query {
   users(offset:Int limit:Int) : UserPage
}

type UserPage {
   data     : [User]
   pageInfo : PageInfo
}

type PageInfo {

    # When paginating forwards, are there more items?
    hasNextPage    : Boolean!

    # When paginating backwards, are there more items?
    hasPreviousPage: Boolean!

    # Total number of records in all page
    total : Long
}
```

Depending on the requirements , you can consider to add an `orderBy` or a `filter` input parameter to the `users` query field to provide more options to the developers to get the result set that they are interested.

If you want to return the user list in the cursor-based pagination style, you can take a look on [Relay Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm).